# EMR Notebook giving "Kernel not found" error

Tags: jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I have followed these steps a few times and I see the "Kernel not found" error on Amazon EMR

1. Create notebook
2. Selected Create a cluster
3. Picked defaults EMR release: emr-5.32.0
   EMR role:EMR_DefaultRole
   EC2 instance profile:EMR_EC2_DefaultRole
4. EC2 key pair:
5. Security group: Use default security groups
6. AWS service role: EMR_Notebooks_DefaultRole

The cluster is created successfully and is waiting. Notebook creation is also successful

When I try to run the notebook, there is no kernel. I try to attach the notebook to a kernel but see the Kernel not found error.

Any ideas about the issue?

Comment: Is your cluster overloaded? Could you check Jupyter enterprise gateway logs on the cluster and see why it is not able to spin up kernel?

Comment: Hi Parag, thank you for your response. I logged an AWS support request. I found out that I cannot run a notebook on EMR using my root account. Once I created an IAM account, everything worked.